# How to define the order of elements in Plotly sunburst diagram?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to generate a sunburst chart with plot_ly. For my special case it would be important if the order of the elements is not determined by the assigned branchvalues, but rather according to their order in the data set.

I have already invested quite some time into finding a solution, am I missing something?

In this minimal example (slightly modified from https://plotly.com/r/sunburst-charts/) a working solution would simply switch places between the elements 'Seth' and 'Cain':

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  labels = c("Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"),
  parents = c("", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve"),
  values = c(65, 12, 14, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4),
  type = 'sunburst',
  branchvalues = 'total'
)

fig
```

Help and tips would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It seems to be an open issue on github: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4823 Therefore I doubt that there is a simple for switiching places.

Comment: @tamtam Thanks a lot for the comment. There has been some recent developments that helped to solve the problem. In the meantime the issue has also been resolved https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/5164